# Save an Excel selection as PDF vector image in Windows

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

In Excel, I want to save a selection of cells as a vector image in PDF format. **The bad way to do this is**

1. File > Export > As PDF/XPS
2. Save as type: PDF
3. Click "Options..." and choose "Selection" under "Publish what"

The problem is that this forces the cells to fit into a standard page template, generating undesirable whitespace.

Instead, **I am able to accomplish what actually I want on the Mac version of Excel** by doing the following:

1. Select the cells
2. In the "Tell me what you want to do..." pane, type `copy`, chose "Copy > Copy as Picture ..."
3. Choose "As shown when printed"
4. Open Preview
5. Choose File > New from clipboard

This gives you a fully PDF whose page dimensions match the selection area exactly. It's a convoluted process, but I have grown reliant on it.

**How can I accomplish the same thing in Windows?**

The Windows version of Excel also has the "Copy as Picture ..." pane, but wherever I paste it, it comes out as a raster image.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an overkill answer using [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0.2/windows/64-bit/exe/dl/):

1. Select the cells
2. In the "Tell me what you want to do..." pane, type copy, chose "Copy > Copy as Picture ..."
3. Choose "As shown when printed"
4. Open Inkscape
5. Edit > Resize Page to Selection
6. File > Save As..., PDF

This is not 100% perfect, because Inkscape resizes to the edge of the objects in the selection, not the selection itself. So the top edges of the text in the top cells are flush with the image margin, instead of including the normal cell padding.

There is an [outstanding feature request](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/2238) for a "New from clipboard" option in Inkscape.